# List in VueJS rerenders every time any variable changes, even unrelated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I download log of 1000+ entries as a JSON. Each entry is a multi-level object. I parse JSON, sort array and filter it. I divided it to 3 different ‘computed’ functions to avoid excessive parsing or sorting. Each ‘computed’ function acts as a pipe, getting data from previous function like:

```
<div v-for="i in cArraySortedFiltered" 
     :key="i.id">...</div>
```

```js
computed: {
  cArray() {
    return parse(json);
  },

  cArraySorted() {
    return cArray.sort(...);
  },

  cArraySortedFiltered() {
    return cArraySorted.filter(...);
  }
}
```

so if I change search string only `arraySortedFiltered()` gonna call.

arraySortedFiltered is rendering as table (not real table but divs stylized as a table).

THE PROBLEM: every time I change any data-section variable via `v-model` it tooks 1-2 sec to reflect changes: `<input v-model="test">`. If I make it via `@input` it works fine: `<input @change="changeVar">`.

Profiler shows that Vue rerenders my big table every time any data-section variable are changing even if nothing related to the table changed, neither input data nor sorting/searching variables. Why is this and how to avoid it?

Manual says Vue is smart and doesn't rerender unchanged data. I checked out — Vue doesn't actually rerender list (I changes a text in a div — it hasn't been rerendered after I changed unrelated variable).

Comment: Can you show some of the content of the table?

Comment: @RoyJ the json or the template?

Comment: The template, sorry.

Comment: Wait, I think I have it: your first computed is returning a function call. Function calls are not tracked responsively, so they have to be called every time. Parse your data into a data item.

Answer (score 1):

Computeds cache changes in reactive elements. You do not have any reactive elements in your computed. It cannot know whether `json` has changed, so it must run the computation every time. Make a `data` item for `cArray` instead of a `computed`.

Comment: `json` is vue variable so if it hasn't been changed `cArray()` would not be computed again either.